# When plugin goal is executed: before or after declared phase?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have a question about maven pom. I have this pom.xml

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <echo>Hello world!</echo>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

when the goal run  is executed? Before or after package phase?

(for Maven lifecycle see [Maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html))

Answer (score 6):

Plugin goal is execute **after** beginning of declared phase (`package`), and before beginning of next phase (`pre-integration-test`).

In this scenerio maven command

```
mvn package
```

should print `Hello World`

Multiple executions in one phase:

> Note: In Maven 2.0.5 and above, multiple goals bound to a phase are
>   executed in the same order as they are declared in the POM, however
>   multiple instances of the same plugin are not supported. Multiple
>   instances of the same plugin are grouped to execute together and
>   ordered in Maven 2.0.11 and above).

and

> When multiple executions are given that match a particular phase, they
>   are executed in the order specified in the POM, with inherited
>   executions running first.

Source: [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Comment: @MariuszS...so we have a multithreads environment. What does it mean after beginning? The package phase execute jar:jar, is my goal executed before or after jar:jar goal?

Comment: Answer updated:  *multiple goals bound to a phase are executed in the same order as they are declared in the POM*.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you have given it will be executed in the package phase, cause you explicit defined it to be executed during the package phase. If you like to get it executed before the package phase you need to use the `prepare-package` phase instead `package`.

Comment: so I can't know when the goal will be executed. I wish to know the exact calling point to my goal: is it impossibile to know?

Comment: As i mentioned in the life-cycle phase. May be you can eleborate a little bit more what you like to achieve otherwise this question does not make really sense.